# Toggling an 'active' class with jQuery, the style remains when clicking button again but class removed in Firefox

Tags: jquery, class, firefox, click, toggle

I have a problem. - only in Firefox

When I use jQuery to toggle a class 'active' on a link. The active style remains if I click the link again. It remains visible until I click somewhere else on the page but only in Firefox yet the class has been removed.

CODE:

```
$('#quick-add-click').click( function() {
  $(this).find('a').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Anyone having any similar issues? Is there a simple fix?

Comment: Do you mean the :active style or .active class?

Comment: Can you post a demo on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), that reproduces this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so the way I fixed it (in a hacky way) was to add `onfocus="blur()"` to the anchor element

Answer (score 0):

Minimal example, cannot see that behaviour on OSX Firefox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            a.active { color: #f00; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#quick-add-click').click(function() {
                    $(this).find('a').toggleClass('active');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="quick-add-click">
            <a href="#">Foobar</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could you check with Firebug where that style comes from when active class is not present anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Mootools or is Mootools being loaded even if you're not using it (happens automatically with Joomla systems).  I had a problem with Firefox/Mootools/VEMap (Bing Maps) maybe you're having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't reproduce it.

However, perhaps you can test if it works without toggle?

```
$('#quick-add-click').click( function() {
  if($(this).find('a').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
  }
});
```